# Android create cardview distance and set layout button

Tags: android

Hi i have create cardview in recyclerview but i have two problem:

1 Distance of cards is too much Fig.1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY4WR.png) Why

2 When i click inputview  keyboard is show but the problem is that button goes upwar Fig.2[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxhum.png)   Why?

This is code:

activity_calendario.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_calendario"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.fra87.eudroid.activity_class.Calendario">



    <Button
        android:text="Salva"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Nome Calendario"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/nome_calendario"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/orario"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/orario" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:hint="Inizio"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nome_calendario"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/inizio" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:hint="Fine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nome_calendario"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/inizio"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/fine" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:hint="Orario"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nome_calendario"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fine"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/orario" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Azioni:"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/label_azioni"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inizio"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/orario"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/orario" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reciclerView_azioni"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label_azioni"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/label_azioni"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/label_azioni" >


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

cards_azioni.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAzione"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="Android Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change `match_parent` to `wrap_content` in `cards_azioni.xml` for parent `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove card view space just do linear layout height wrap content

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewAzione"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Android Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and you can set in manifest like this..

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"> </activity>
```